# C array vs pointer in these examples

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

This question doesn't require any initial explanation, other that to show the examples.
Why does this work (prints the contents of array `a`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[100];

void check(int **b)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        printf("%d ", b[0][i]);
}

int main()
{
    int *arr = a;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    
    check(&arr);

    return 0;
}
```

and this doesn't (compiles with onlinegdb c compiler, but prints nothing)?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[100];

void check(int **c)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        printf("%d ", c[0][i]);
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i;
    }

    check((int**)&a);

    return 0;
}
```

I understand that array is a special data type in C, but shouldn't casting it to a pointer type or assigning it to one be the same? Is there a way to make the second example work without the additional pointer?

Comment: Please describe what "but this doesn't" acutally means. Do you get compilation errors? Do you get wrong output? What do you get, what do you expect?

Comment: Ask yourself. If you dereference `c` within `check`, where does it point to in both cases. Is it a pointer? Can you dereference again?

Comment: If i dereference `c` within `check`, I expect it to point to the first element of array `a`. If I double dereference it, I expect it to give the value of the first element of arrray `a`. I expect the same thing to happen when dereferencing `b` in the first example.

Comment: `&a` naturally has type `int (*)[100]` but your second example is explicitly converting it to type `int **` to fool the `check` function, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @IanAbbott Is the a way to make the second example work?

Comment: If you point to first element of `a` how do you think you can dereference it? All elements of `a` are `int`, no pointers.

Comment: You do need the additional pointer, but it does not need to be a declared variable. A *compound literal* can be used (which is like an anonymous, initialized variable in this context). For example: `check((int **){&a[0]})` or `check((int **){a})`.

Comment: You can also make `check` to expect your type of array: `void check(int (*c)[100])` but usually one provides a pointer to the first element of the array and its size: `void check(int *c, size_t n)` an call it like `check(a, 100)` (within `check` you then print `c[i]`)

Comment: @Gerhardh By point to I mean have the address of the first element of `a`. Dereferencing it should then give the value of the `int` at the specified address.

Comment: Yes, `c` points to the first element of `a`. But this is before any dereferencing. Then you dereference it once: `c[0]` accesses the first element of `a` but thinks it is a pointer. In first example, `c[0]` actually accesses your `arr` variable which really is a pointer. Dereferencing the second time `c[0][i]` makes a pointer from `a[0]` and tries to dereference this `int` value. That won't fly. Again, in first example, dereferencing `c[0][i]` dereferences `arr` and correctly accesses the elements of `a`.

Comment: @Gerhardh I've just realized that `&a` is equal to `a` or `&a[0]` (all contain the address of the first element of `a`). Now everything you said makes sense to me. Thank you.

Comment: That is true. But if it wasn't, then your first example wouldn't work.